Migrate thousand of data from excel into DB
I have rental data from year 2019-2024 in an excel
In that excel, the data consists of tenant name, monthly payment details from jan - dec each year
I have done massaging the data
I need to mapping the payment details and tenant details because both details are in different table
Can you suggest what tools can I use so I can mapping the payment details with their tenants details
Currently, tenant can pay multiple month in one receipt number, so I need cater for that duplicated receipt number also for my migration

Save both tables as CSV then import them using LOAD DATA. Simple query with JOIN will then solve your need.

I already did that, the current issue is I need to mapping the data in each tables using foreign key, I can do that manually but it will take a long time to finish it because i need to look at one by one. I need some guidance to make my mapping easier

I need to mapping the data in each tables using foreign key If you need to set the relation then you'd create according FOREIGN KEY. If you need to obtain mapped output then you need in common query which uses proper JOIN. See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3, provide structures, sample data (3-5 rows per table is enough) and desired output for shown data.
